# Only one item's elements in flex row is selectable

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm learning React by starting to build a simple webpage (I know, overkill.) but I ran across a weird issue.

So I have three "bubbles" on my homepage each containing an icon, title, and text. I am using flex in their parent container to align them as a row but when I do this I can only select the title and text of the last "bubble".

If I choose `flex-direction: column;` (or if I don't set a direction) I am able to select the text of all three bubbles. If I choose: `flex-direction: row;` and `flex-wrap: wrap;` and then make the window smaller so one of the bubbles goes to the next line, I am able to select the text from 1/2 of the bubbles on line one and the text from the bubble on line two.

Also the :hover is no longer working in that last section of CSS code.

Been at this problem for a couple of days and it makes no sense to me. Thanks in advance for the help. See code below.

```css
.home-services {
  padding: 50px;
  background-color: bisque;
  transform: skewY(-3deg) translateY(-55px);
  z-index: -1;
}

.home-bubbles {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  transform: skewY(3deg) translateY(50px);
  width: 100%;
  user-select: all;
  z-index: -1;
}

.home-services-bubble {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 2px 3px #ddd;
  width: 29%;
}

.bubble-icon {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #f64a01;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  font-size: 3vw;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 100px;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.home-services-bubble:hover .bubble-icon {
  transform: translateY(-5px);
  background-color: black;
  box-shadow: 2px 3px #ddd;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.2/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="home-services">
  <div class="home-bubbles">
    <div class="home-services-bubble">
      <div class="bubble-icon">
        <i class="fas fa-search fa-2x"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="bubble-title">
        <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="bubble-text">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="home-services-bubble">
      <div class="bubble-icon">
        <i class="fas fa-wind  fa-2x"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="bubble-title">
        <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="bubble-text">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="home-services-bubble">
      <div class="bubble-icon">
        <i class="fas fa-sign  fa-2x"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="bubble-title">
        <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="bubble-text">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try removing user-select: all;

Answer (score 0):

The [`user-select`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/user-select) property with the value `all` selects the whole text on a simple click. Just remove it like this:

```
.home-bubbles {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  transform: skewY(3deg) translateY(50px);
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! 

I actually added this while troubleshooting. I realized the root problem was in a ```<div class="container"``` that wrapped everything. I had the following CSS: 
```.content{
  flex: 1;
   z-index: -1; 
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}```

Removing the ```display: flex;``` and z-index fixed my issue and activated the user-select property which I disabled now and everything is now functioning as expected.